# Java - Returning a abstract class

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am developing a web application in jsf

I have these classes

Abstract:

- RepositoryBase
- ManagedBeanCRUD
- EntityBase

Classes:

- Client            extends EntityBase
- ClientRepository  extends RepositoryBase
- ClientManagedBean extends ManagedBeanCRUD

However I am having trouble to implement a save method at ManagedBeanCRUD

during this method I need a Repository, so I have a RepositoryBase rep = repositoryfactory.getFactory((entity.getClass()));

I tried to implement the repositoryFactory in many ways, but still without success.

Anyone has any idea how I could do this???

thank you in advance

```
public class  ManagedBeanCRUD < T extends EntityBase> () {
   protected T newEntity;

   public void save() {      
    Repositoryfactory factory =  new Repositoryfactory();
    RepositoryBase<T> rep = factory.getFactory((entity.getClass()));
    rep.persiste(newEntity);
  }
}


public class FactoryRepository < T extends EntityBase> () {

public RepositoryBase<T> getFactory(Class newEntity) {
    if(newEntity == Client.class) {
         return new ClientRepository();
    } else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
}

public class ClientManagedBean extends CRUDBean<Client> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Clietn client = new Client();

public void setSalve(){
    this.setNewEntity(this.client);
    this.salvar();
    this.client = new Client();
}
```

}

public class ClientRepository extends RepositoryBase{

```
@Override
protected Class<Client> getRuntimeClass() {
    return Client.class;
}
```

}

Comment: Share your attempt to implement it.

Comment: What is the problem that you have with it?

Comment: hi guys I have update the question, I hope this makes thing clear to you, please let me know if you need any other information